# MIN() vs LEN() Behaviors as Shortest String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve a question in HackerRank called "Your Weather Observation Station 5",
the question asks to return the shortest and longest city names within the provided table.

Demonstration to clarify my confusion:

`SELECT MIN(City) FROM STATION;` Output: A name of city with 4 characters.

`SELECT MIN(LEN(City)) FROM STATION;` Output: 3.

Why the MIN() function output isn't a city name with 3 characters? I would appreciate an explanation of this behavior.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `min(city)` is nothing to do with the number of characters, it's the minimum value ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "MIN" a string column, you will get the alphabetically first listing. It has nothing to do with the length of the string.

Example, "Albuquerque" appears alphabetically before "Miami".

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still looking for the solution, I did this challenge from hacker rank and this is the query that works:

```
select
    city,
    length(city)
from station
where city =
(
    select
        city
    from station
        where length(city) =
        (
            select
                max(length(city))
            from station
            limit 1
        ) 
        order by 1 asc
        limit 1
) or city =
(
    select
        city
    from station
        where length(city) =
        (
            select
                min(length(city))
            from station
            limit 1
        )
        order by 1 
        limit 1
)
order by 1
```